# MVC dropdownlist set selected value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Hey I have tried following to set the selected value for dropdownlist.
In My controller:

```
u.Roles = new List<AspNetRole>();
foreach (var role in db.AspNetRoles)
{
    u.Roles.Add(role);
}
```

And in my View:

```
 @Html.DropDownList(Model.role.Id, new SelectList(Model.Roles, "Id", "Name"), htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control"})
```

But still not working, I did not got the selected value. When debugging I can see that `Model.role.Id` contains the selected value.

Note also that the Id is of type string, because it is hashed. 
What I am doing wrong?

Comment: your code isn't that bad really.. you just missed the part where you tell `SelectList` what the selected value should be. `SelectList(Model.Roles, "Id", "Name", Model.role.Id)`

Comment: You not doing anything wrong. If the value of `Model.role.Id` matches one of the `Roles.Id` values then that option will be selected. Check the html your generating to ensure that there is an option with a value that does match exactly.

Comment: Thanks, that was all I needed =)

Answer (score 4):

There are few ways of display DropDownList in MVC. I like the following approach.

*Note: You need a collection of **SelectListItem** in model.*

### Model

```
public class MyModel
{
    public int SelectedId { get; set; }
    public IList<SelectListItem> AllItems { get; set; }

    public MyModel()
    {
        AllItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
    }
}
```

### Controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new MyModel();
        model.AllItems = new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem { Text = "One",  Value = "1"},
            // *** Option two is selected by default ***
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Two",  Value = "2", Selected = true},
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Three",  Value = "3"}
        };
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyModel model)
    {
        // Get the selected value
        int id = model.SelectedId;
        return View();
    }
}
```

### View

```
@model DemoMvc.Controllers.MyModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedId, Model.AllItems)
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

Comment: This is basically the approach I recommend, with a few modifications for cases where you don't always have a legal value pre-selected as a default. In those cases, you can make the Model property nullable (`int?`) and then add something like `new SelectListItem() { Text = "-- Select --", Value =""}` to the top of the List. This also works nicely with DataAnnotations and `[Required]`.

Comment: You should not set the `Selected` property of `SelectListItem` when your binding to a property. Its the value of the property which determines which option is selected and manually setting the `Selected` property is just ignored (the HtmlHelper method overwrites it so its pointless extra overhead)

Comment: Thank you for your effort =) I like it =)